# Algorithm to simulate live poll

Tags: algorithm, d3.js

I want write an algorithm to simulate a live poll.

The audience has 4 different options to vote. I visualize the percentage of each option a,b,c,d.

So I came up with an algorithm that would give me an array of 4 random numbers that sums 100.

```
dataset = [];
a = randombetween(0, max);
b = randombetween(0, max - a);
c = randombetween(0, max - a - b);
d = max - a - b - c;
dataset.push(a, b, c, d);
shuffle(dataset);
```

This code is executed every 2 seconds to update the poll results.

To make my algorithm more realistic I want changes to be more gradual. 
I want to create a inicial random result and then increase/decrease the poll results gradually. Let's say a poll result should not increase/decrease more than 5% per update.

Here is a fiddle to play around with it: [Live Poll](https://jsfiddle.net/adai183/7un651z2/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simulate a constant rate of votes being submitted? This way, when you calculate the percentages, the changes will be smaller when more people have already voted. This seems like it might work better than changing the percentages. I threw this together just as a demonstration (https://jsfiddle.net/ovkfw577/1/ )

```
var votes = [0,0,0,0];
var dataset = [0,0,0,0];
var dataSize = 4;
var voteRate = 10;

// Algorithm to simulate the further voting process
var updateData = function() {

    var total = 0;
    dataset = [0,0,0,0];

    // add random amount of votes
    for(i=0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        var randomVotes = randombetween(0,voteRate);
        votes[i] += randomVotes;
      total += votes[i];
    }

    // calculate percentages
    for(i=0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        dataset[i] = votes[i] / total * 100;
    }

    // so poll bars don't completely stall later on.
    // not entirely necessary, but helps polling
    // appear more active.
    voteRate *= 1.2;

    drawVis();
    $("svg").fadeIn("slow");
};
```